# how to check particular node online or offline status in jenkins using pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to check the node/slave status with parameterized pipeline script as the code given below

```
import hudson.model.*
pipeline {
   agent none

   parameters {
      string(defaultValue: "", description: '', name: 'JUMP_HOST')
   }

   stages {
       stage("NODE"){
          steps{
              script{
                def axis = []
                //for (slave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
                //    println slave.getComputer().isOnline()

                 if (hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getSlave(params.JUMPHOST).getComputer().isOnline().toString() == "true") {
                   axis += slave.name + " node is online"
                 }else{
                     axis += slave.name + " node is offline"
                 }
                }

                println axis

          }
       }
   }
}
```

After the executing the above code i am getting the error like below as given:

```
 Started by user administrator
 Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
  [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
  [Pipeline] stage
  [Pipeline] { (NODE)
  [Pipeline] script
  [Pipeline] {
  [Pipeline] }
  [Pipeline] // script
  [Pipeline] }
  [Pipeline] // stage
  [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
    hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson.model.Hudson.slaves() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [ansible_master]
    Possible solutions: save(), save(), getSlaves(), setSlaves(java.util.List), sleep(long), getSlave(java.lang.String)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:16)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
   at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:84)
   at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor231.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:76)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor236.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:186)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:370)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:282)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:270)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:66)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `getNode`. https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#slaves

```
if (hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getNode(params.JUMPHOST).toComputer().isOnline()) {
    echo "node is online"
} else {
    echo "node is offline"
}
```

Comment: What would be the declarative pipeline syntax ?

Comment: Currently, `Jenkins.getInstance().getNode(nodeLabel)?.toComputer()?.isOnline()` is the preferred way to check.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what we use:

```
import hudson.model.Node


// This method collects a list of Node names from the current Jenkins instance
@NonCPS
def onlineNodeNames() {
    String[] free_nodes = []
     for (Node node in jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.nodes) {
         // Make sure slave is online
         if (node != null && node.toComputer() != null && node.toComputer().online) {
             free_nodes += node.name 
         }
     }
    return free_nodes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This working for me !!

```
jenkins.model.Jenkins.get().computers.each{ node->
     NODENM=node.name
     NODELB=node.node.labelString
     NODEST=node.online
     println("Node: $NODENM(Label: $NODELB) OnlineStatus: $NODEST")
}
```